# How to hide li tags, if the id is not in JSON using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a fixed menu with li tags. I want to display only the li tags whose id is present in JSON. If the id is not in JSON the li tag will be not displayed.

This is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"><a href="#">Screen 1</a></li>
    <li id="2"><a href="#">Screen 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="3"><a href="#">Screen 3</a></li>
            <li id="4"><a href="#">Screen 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="5"><a href="#">Screen 5</a></li>
    <li id="6"><a href="#">Screen 6</a></li>
    <li id="7"><a href="#">Screen 7</a></li>
    <li id="8"><a href="#">Screen 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8{
    display:none;
}
```

This is my JSON:

```
[
  {  "ScreenID": 2,    
    "ScreenName": "Screen 2"  
  },
  {
    "ScreenID": 3,    
    "ScreenName": "Screen 3"
  },
  { 
    "ScreenID": 5,    
    "ScreenName": "Screen 5"   
  }
]
```

Now, only li tag with id 2, 3, and 5 should be visible.

Comment: Any effort on your side? :)

Comment: Sounds like you should hide them all and loop through and unhide the ones that are there. Simple [forEach loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Side note: `id` values starting with digits are valid HTML, but CSS ID *selectors* cannot validly start with a digit. That is, `#1` is an invalid CSS selector. Suggest making your life easier and not using `id`s that start with digits. (Note: jQuery will handle `$("#1")` for you, because it will optimize that into a call to `document.getElementById`, but it will fail if you do anything more interesting, like `$("#1 span")` to get spans within that element. Best not to rely on non-standard, undocumented quirks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(jsonArray, function(index, value) {
  var id = jsonArray[index].ScreenID;
  $('#' + id).show();
});
```

Comment: Great. Encourage more no-effort questions. Because we're not already buried under them.